# Error Cannot set property 'filterPredicate' of undefined in Angular Material

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-material, observable

I'm implementing filtering functionality on a table and I'm getting the following errors when I debug.

```
core.js:6228 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'filterPredicate' of undefined
    at new IssuedLicenseListComponent
```

Already declared the `listData` and it's a `MatTableDataSource` which has the property `filterPredicate` what could be the issue here?

**Model**

```
export interface LicenseIssued {
  issue_date: Date;
  valid_from: Date;
  expiry_date: Date;
  amount_paid: any;
  receipt_no: any;

}
```

**Here is the code from the component**

```
.....
  listData: MatTableDataSource<LicenseIssued>;

  get fromDate() { return this.filterForm.get('fromDate').value; }
  get toDate() { return this.filterForm.get('toDate').value; }

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    private spinner: NgxSpinnerService,
    private dataService: DataService,
    private route: Router,

    ) {

      this.pipe = new DatePipe('en');
      this.listData.filterPredicate = (data, filter) =>{
        if (this.fromDate && this.toDate) {

          console.log('filtered')
          console.log(data)
          console.log(data.issue_date)
          return data.issue_date >= this.fromDate && data.issue_date <= this.toDate;
        }
        return true;
      }


    }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.getAllIssuedLicenses();

    /** spinner starts on init **/

    this.spinner.show();
    /** spinner starts afer 5 secs**/
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.spinner.hide();

    }, 7000);
  }


  getAllIssuedLicenses() {
    this.liquorService.getAllIssuedLicenses().subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res)
        this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(res.data);
      },

      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );

    this.listData.sort = this.sort;

    const sortState: Sort = {active: 'id', direction: 'desc'};
    this.sort.active = sortState.active;
    this.sort.direction = sortState.direction;
    this.sort.sortChange.emit(sortState);

    this.listData.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

   applyFilter() {
    this.listData.filter = ''+Math.random();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare **listData** as below.

```
listData = new MatTableDataSource();
```

Comment: It's ok now, but the filter isn't working I get empty results

Comment: create stackblitz of you issue, than i can check, you post the question as **filterPredicate** undefined.

Comment: In filterPredicate you need to set the filter. see the code this.dataSource.filterPredicate =
      (data: any, filter: string) => !filter || data.level == filter;
To filter you need to do the code as 
filterSearch(level) {
  this.dataSource.filter = level;
}

Comment: If the given answer is works for your 'filterPredicate' of undefined problem. Please upvode and accept.

Comment: I was following up on this example and it's working perfectly the difference with my code is that I'm getting data from a service (it's not hard coded). Here is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pkkvbd-cdtxwz-date-range-filter-jzlwxr?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts

Comment: what is the type of issue_date. set the type to date.